# When creating a new user in WordPress how can I default the "show admin toolbar" checkbox to false?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

When creating a **new** user in WordPress, the checkbox is defaulted to being ticked for:

> "Show Toolbar when viewing site"

I want to allow all users to potentially see the toolbar if they choose, but I'd like to disable this to being false when creating a new user for the first time.

Essentially, I want to make the toolbar to be "opt-in" rather than "opt-out".

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'new_user_opt_in_adminbar', 10, 1 );

function new_user_opt_in_adminbar $user_id ) {

        update_user_meta($user_id,  'show_admin_bar_front',  'false');

}
```